# React JS drop down does not get default selected based on value set

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I was having some problem when trying to set default selected value for drop down in React JS. Following as per my dropdown:

```
<ValidationField
              name="receivedBy"
              inputComponent="react-select"
              selectClassName="d-block"
              placeholder="Please select"
              options={adminList.map((item) => ({ label: item.fullName, value: item.id }))}
              value={adminList.filter(function(option) {
                return option.label === {receivedBy};
              })}
```

In my ValidationField which is a customized class:

```
if (inputComponent === 'react-select') {
    const selectedValue = options ? options.find((option) => option.value === currentValue || option.label === currentValue) || '' : '';
    return (
      <Select
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        isAsync={isAsync}
        isAppendToBody={!noPortal}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={selectedValue}
        options={options || []}
        isClearable={isClearable}
        isDisabled={disabled}
        noDefaultValue
        isError={isError}
        className={selectClassName}
        small
        onChange={(item) => {
          const value = item?.value || undefined;
          if (setFieldValue) setFieldValue(name, value || '');
          if (onChange) onChange(value);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Sample data to populate the dropdown:

```
0: {id: 'admin_1', fullName: 'Admin 1'}
1: {id: 'admin_2', fullName: 'Admin 2'}
2: {id: 'admin', fullName: 'Admin 3'}
```

I managed to populate the dropdown with the data above, however, when I tried to set the reeivedBy to one of the drop down item, the drop down doesnt get default selected. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion you are not passing `currentValue` in here

```
const selectedValue = options ? options.find((option) => option.value === currentValue || option.label === currentValue) || '' : '';
```

So, every time selected value is empty string.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to amend this?

Comment: Just pass the `currentValue` prop from `ValidationField`.

Comment: Hi, just passed in the currentValue but unfortunately, it doesnt work still